# I want a jquery date picker to change default date to text from a hyper link

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a hyper link say 02/14/2016 and I want default date which datepicker picks as current date changed to the text in the hyperlink . I have tried something like this:

```
$("#myid").datepicker("setDate", document.getelementbyID(id of datepicker).innerHTML);
```

Please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v8v15pd2/ for more details. Any help would be appreciated.

However My actual hyperlink is this :

```
<a href="#"><h3>2015<br>December 15</h3></a>
```

for simplicity i have taken a date in mm/dd/yyyy format above.

Comment: include the js which provides the `datepicker` in the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things were wrong in your code. I have modified them.

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#hiddenDate').datepicker({
        changeYear: 'true',
        changeMonth: 'true',
        startDate: '01/01/1985',
        firstDay: 1
    });
    $('#pickDate').click(function(e) {
        var hyper = document.getElementById("pickDate"); // id should be in quote
        $("#hiddenDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date(hyper.innerHTML)); //Selector was incorrect and you need to parse the date.
        $('#hiddenDate').datepicker("show");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And you forgot to include jQuery libraries in jsfiddle.

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/v8v15pd2/3/

Comment: like specified above

Comment: <a href="#"><h3>2015<br>December 15</h3></a>

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bellow

```
$('#hiddenDate').datepicker('setDate', $("#pickDate").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

An all-jQuery option:

```
$('#pickDate').click(function(e) {
    $("#hiddenDate").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", $(this).text());
    $('#hiddenDate').datepicker("show");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As long as the date in `$(this).text()` is in the format used by the datepicker, there is no need to parse it, you can just use it as-is.

I don't even see `setDate` in the datepicker docs, so I used `option defaultDate ...`.